# How can I reproduce a SHA512 hash in C# that fits the PHP SHA512?

Tags: c#, .net, php, hash, sha512

The question is pretty much self-explanatory. I Googled many sites, many methods, tried many encodings, but I can't get it to match.

I'm trying to make the string "asdasd" match. (http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?text=asdasd)

Comment: PHP doesn't have a SHA-512 implementation as far as I know. Could you post the code you are using?

Comment: I was wrong. PHP does seem to support quite a few hash functions: http://www.php.net/hash

Comment: But I still would like to see the code you're using to answer this question. (sorry for the spamming the comments :-D )

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

```
using System.Security.Cryptography

public static string HashPassword(string unhashedPassword)
{
    return BitConverter.ToString(new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(unhashedPassword))).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: Easy, nice, small, fast lets say perfect!

Comment: Isn't SHA612CryptoServiceProvider a disposable object?  Will this leak a service provider instance on each call?

Comment: there's a sha612 now? could have swore it was 512... ^_^

Comment: Works great, but note that I had to call ToLower() instead of ToUpper() at the end to achieve identical results with PHP's hash("sha512", $data).

Answer (score 1):

BitConverter works just fine ...

```
var testVal = "asdasd";
var enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
var bytes = enc.GetBytes( testVal );

var sha = new SHA512Managed();
var result = sha.ComputeHash( bytes );

var resStr = BitConverter.ToString( result );
var nodash = resStr.Replace( "-", "" );

nodash.Dump();
```

(Fixed for 512-bit hash, sorry :)

Comment: I don't know if that's just a typo in your code, but he was asking for sha512, not sha256.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent several hours trying to get a .NET hash function to match PHP's Crypt function. Not fun.

There are multiple challenges here, since the PHP implementation of Crypt returns a base64 encoded string, and doesn't do multiple hashing iterations (e.g. 5000 is default for Crypt.) I was not able to get similar outputs from .NET using several libraries, until I found CryptSharp. It accepts a salt similar to PHP's (or the original C) function (e.g. `"$6$round=5000$mysalt"`). Note that there is no trailing $, and that if you don't provide a salt it will autogenerate a random one.

You can find CryptSharp here:
http://www.zer7.com/software.php?page=cryptsharp

Good background reading:
- http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt