# Why C# sha512 hash value is different with PHP crypt method?

Tags: c#, php, crypt, sha512

I am using the same salt and password, but the hash value is different in C# and PHP. Why is that?

```
string password = "password";
string salt = "salt";
```

C# :

HMACSHA512 hmac = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt));

```
        byte[] bithash = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

        for (int i = 0; i < 7778;i++){
            bithash = hmac.ComputeHash(bithash);
        }

        Console.WriteLine( Convert.ToBase64String(bithash) );

uQobtR+v8PovsSOjCZ9tZyOsfUYWw+xZSOMEuljCzXdezVs8LiM85I1JRQsVpKGSalrC5xTu5sU2f127Bw3DoA==
```

PHP:

```
crypt('password','$6$rounds=7778$salt$'); 

QVysRURDsOGt7/ig9jE7JNutVD2XWO5h9gmBmvC5HtEUFUtVNugF3GWJe6CwFkVNq91kJY8yL5QVPQYXUzhoM1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reproduce a SHA512 hash in C# that fits the PHP SHA512?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419069/how-can-i-reproduce-a-sha512-hash-in-c-sharp-that-fits-the-php-sha512)

Comment: no, this one has salt and hash counts. thanks.

Comment: Where did the `7778` come from and what does it mean? Also, keep in mind that the `rounds=1` parameter will automatically be increased to 1000 as defined in https://akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested.

Comment: yeah, 7778 means php and unix hash for 7778 counts too. I fixed it and post my answser. thanks, mate.

Answer (score 0):

finanly I found a method with library: https://www.zer7.com/software.php?page=cryptsharp

```
string password = "password";
string salt = "$6$rounds=7777$salt";

CryptSharp.Sha512Crypter sha512Crypter = new Sha512Crypter();

var hash = sha512Crypter.Crypt(password, salt);
Console.WriteLine(hash);
Console.ReadLine();
```